# What is the meaning of KDB table of type 0h?

Tags: kdb

This is what I am observing:

```
q)type select date,time from table
98h
q)type select date,time,size from table
0h
q)select date,time,size from table
date       time                          size  
------------------------------------------------
2007.01.03 2007.01.03D09:31:00.000000000 200    
2007.01.03 2007.01.03D09:31:00.000000000 313869 
2007.01.03 2007.01.03D09:31:00.000000000 114852 
2007.01.03 2007.01.03D09:31:00.000000000 566600 
..
```

Why does the resulting table have type 0h? What is the meaning of it? Why adding size to the query changes the result type? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It means a mixed list - https://code.kx.com/q/basics/datatypes/

Thus - size is a mixed type. You can group the column into its types and identify the offending indices by running:

```
exec i group type each size from table
```

To get the column into a typed column you will need to run a cast to convert them to your required type. Perhaps your time column has a mix of ints and longs for example, just cast them to what you require.

Comment: Somehow it does not work: "q)exec i group type each size from table" results in 'nyi error (table is a partitioned DB). And if I try to do "q)t: select from table" first, I get 'type error. "q)meta table" prints correct types: date:d, time:p, size:e.

Comment: "q) t: select date,time,size from table; exec i group type each size from t" results in 'type error (indicating "i" as the source of the problem).

Comment: what does "q)select distinct type each size,count distinct type each size from table" give you? Does it give you multiple types for size? You needn't worry about date and size for now - they look ok.

Comment: This is the result of "select distinct type each size,count distinct type each size from table": ([] size:enlist[-8]; size1:enlist[1]). 

I have found a solution to the problem, but I do not understand why it works: "q)select from table where not null isin" produces expected result (type 98h) even though the added selection does not remove any rows: "q)select from table where null isin" produces an empty table (count=0, type 98h).

Comment: Result of "q)select distinct type each time,count distinct type each time from table" : ([] time:enlist[-12]; time1:enlist[1]). Result of "q)select distinct type each date,count distinct type each date from table" : ([] date:enlist[-14]; date1:enlist[1]).